# get pageload time using command line - linux

Tags: linux, curl, time, pageload

I am stuck with a problem. I have list of 10 URL. I need to calculate the page load time.

I am presently using curl for getting the page load time:

> time curl www.growingcraft.com

Second method:

> wget www.growingcraft.com

The problem is that, this gives me the time taken to download the page, but :

1. Does this file also includes the Javascript, css and images time?
2. What is there are some external reference to some images (as in this case). How to calculate the time taken to load those images?

Is there any other way I can calculate page load time in Linux which will be more effective/accurate?

Comment: i think you should look into using apachebench for this sort of thing..

Comment: Thanks. Will explore that.

Comment: This is a question rather for serverfault. You have your answer there: http://serverfault.com/questions/124952/testing-a-website-from-linux-command-line . Please consider deleting this questin from stackoverflow

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
time wget -pq --no-cache --delete-after www.growingcraft.com
```

`-p` makes it download all the resources (images, scripts, etc.)

`-q` makes it quiet.

The other options should be self-explanatory.

Comment: This worked for me to certain level, but not complete. I think it downloaded the resources that were hosted in the same domain, but this website also had some images hosted in google drive. I think those were not taken into account.

I was trying to cross check the results with tools.pingdom.com. I can see that there is a big difference in the results obtained. Cannot understand the reason though.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal oops, you need the -H option to make it span external hosts. But then you have the problem that wget doesn't download things in parallel, so your load time will go way up. You could try something like aria2, but eventually you will run into the problem that none of these tools can detect resources loaded by scripts, which do affect overall load time as perceived by your users. I would really suggest looking into [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html) if you're serious about automating network performance tests.